link is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. at assertValidProps
function getUsers() {
axios.get('http://localhost:80/api/users/').then(function(response)
{
setUsers(response.data);useState
})
}
I used axios.get method to fetch data from an api and list it. the data is received from api I checked it in console but the above error is shown .How to fix it.
